# this undefined methods and members within callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I can use the following to save a new document to my mongodb database.

```
User.prototype.save = function (fn) {
  var user = new userModel({
    user: this.user,
    pass: this.pass
  });
  console.log('user: ' +user);

  this.hashPassword (user.pass, function (err, salt, hash) {
    if (err) return fn (err);
    this.pass = hash;
    user.salt = salt;
    user.pass = hash;
    user.save (function (err, product, numberAffected) {
      if (err) return fn (err);
      return fn(undefined);
    });
  });
};
```

Now I'm trying to check if the user already exists before saving it

```
User.prototype.save = function (fn) {
  // See if the username exists
  userModel.findOne ({ 'user': this.user }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return fn (err);
    if (!user) {
      user = new userModel({
        user: this.user,
        pass: this.pass
      });
      console.log('user: ' +user);

      this.hashPassword (user.pass, function (err, salt, hash) {
        if (err) return fn (err);
        this.pass = hash;
        user.salt = salt;
        user.pass = hash;
        user.save (function (err, product, numberAffected) {
          if (err) return fn (err);
          return fn(undefined);
        });
      });
    } else {
      // TODO: update all the user fields
      console.log ('user already exists');
    }
  });
}
```

this.hashPassword is no longer found `TypeError: Object #<Promise> has no method 'hashPassword'` and the fields of user are now undefined.  How can I use `this` within these callbacks?

EDIT 1:

Taking a closer look I also notice that `this.pass = hash;` in the first snippet also does nothing to the object I care about.

Comment: on line 2 

`var self = this`

then, `self.hashPassword()`

Comment: Makes sense and works; feel free to leave an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on line 2

`var self = this`

then,

`self.hashPassword()`

In full:

```
User.prototype.save = function (fn) {
  var self = this;
  // See if the username exists
  userModel.findOne ({ 'user': self.user }, function (err, user) {
    if (err) return fn (err);
    if (!user) {
      user = new userModel({
        user: self.user,
        pass: self.pass
      });
      console.log('user: ' +user);

      self.hashPassword (user.pass, function (err, salt, hash) {
        if (err) return fn (err);
        self.pass = hash;
        user.salt = salt;
        user.pass = hash;
        user.save (function (err, product, numberAffected) {
          if (err) return fn (err);
          return fn(undefined);
        });
      });
    } else {
      // TODO: update all the user fields
      console.log ('user already exists');
    }
  });
}
```